# Building a Salophen-Complex with Iron(III) and Cyanate

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

[image]

I prepared the compound in (1). Now I want to prepare the complex with a cyanate ligand (2).

Is it possible to prepare Fe(OCN)3 or should I form the chloro-complex first and then change the Ligand?

I searched for available salts, however there is no iron salt. There are only potassium cyanate, sodium cyanate and other salts. Is there a particular reason why iron salts are not available?